# why my following fiddle giving output without any print call?

Tags: javascript

I have one piece of code as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8514414755716493";
/* AdX_Washington_Examiner */
google_ad_slot = "9465392777";
google_ad_width = 320;
google_ad_height = 50;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Why this code is giving output as "`}//]]>`" ??

I have not written any print call still it is giving output..

Here is my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/akshaynikte/ryLPf/6/#

Comment: You can't use a `<script>`-tag in this place on jsfiddle, as it will be placed within another one. Also note, that `<!-- -->` is invalid within a `<script>`-tag. This will result in a semantic error. Use `/* comment */` or `// comment` instead.

Comment: @Akki You can edit your code like --
<script type="text/javascript"/>/*<!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8514414755716493";
 AdX_Washington_Examiner 
google_ad_slot = "9465392777";
google_ad_width = 320;
google_ad_height = 50;
//-->
*/
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few excerpts from the [`jsFiddle` documentation page](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html) :

The [`JavaScript`](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#javascript) panel

> Code entered in this panel will be placed in header’s script block,
>   that is between `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>`.

The [`Add Resources`](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#add-resources) section

> CSS or JS (with appropriate extension) which should be loaded after
>   the framework. It’s a perfect place to put libraries which are
>   framework independent, like RaphaelJS

So, the correct way to work with the script in your question would be:

1. Add the following to the `JavaScript` panel.

   ```
   <!--
       google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8514414755716493";
       /* AdX_Washington_Examiner */
       google_ad_slot = "9465392777";
       google_ad_width = 320;
       google_ad_height = 50;
   -->
   ```
2. Add `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js` to the `Add resources` section on the left side of the page.

Here's a link to a properly configured sample: http://jsfiddle.net/edywd/.

Comment: you'll still get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < with that answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug on fiddler (or that it doesn't allow `script` tags on javascript panel) , if you change the script to anything else, you'll see that it happens the same.

You should place your script on HTML panel, that works fine according my tests.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8514414755716493";
/* AdX_Washington_Examiner */
google_ad_slot = "9465392777";
google_ad_width = 320;
google_ad_height = 50;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

you cant use script tags in  js textarea of jsfiddle,it is js only, if you want use script tags , put them in the html textarea of jsfiddle